# Konvajs : how to get bowser co-ordinates corresponding to canvas co-ordinates from canvas object?

Tags: python, konvajs, react-konva, konva, konvajs-reactjs

I am trying to automate konvajs canvas UI.

when using tools like selenium or playwright, the **click event clicks on browser co-ordinates** which are different from canvas co-ordinates.

I **wish to click on canvas co-ordinates**. Therefore, I need some api or code which gives browser co-ordinates corresponding to canvas co-ordinates.

Please share your valuable inputs

Answer (score 0):

```
windowToCanvas(y) {
    return { y: y - 50 }
}
```

`y` is `e.clientY`, `50` is `stage.y`.

Comment: Kindly add a line or two to explain what you are doing. This will help the readers to understand the answer more clearly.